# Recycler View, instead of creating a new View Holder, add layout to previous ViewHolder

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

In a chat app, I create view holders for each message, but if the same person sends several messages in a row, I want to add a view to the previous ViewHolder, instead of creating a new ViewHolder, how can I stop the creation of a new ViewHolder, should I do so from the adapter or elsewhere?

Comment: you should always update the recyclerView using the adapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter will only create the same amount of views as the one you return on `getItemCount` (not to be confused with the current displayed and allocated viewholders). That means if you want to limit your views, you should limit this count. As for the dynamic view, you should do it in the `onCreateViewHolder` method of the adapter and bind data in the viewholder.

Comment: what if I return null in the onCreateViewHolder, will that avoid creating a new view?

Comment: ended up modifying the dataset, with a List < Lists<messageObjs> > instead of the original Lists<messageObjs> and adding the views programatically in the onBindViewHolder, thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can explore using https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#notifyItemChanged(int,%20java.lang.Object). instead of adding a new element. You specify the position and a payload (maybe your several messages?) to be delivered through onBindViewHolder. Also, remember to update your dataset accordingly.

Comment: This was very interesting indeed, but the payload was not being received, ended up modifying the dataset all together,